# How to add play pause button on slider Revolution Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, jquery-ui, slider

I created a button for pause and play the slides in slider revolution. I want to add some code for that . Anyone, please help me to add the code for pause and play the slider. Sample buttons are here on the slider. https://www.bmwusa.com/

Comment: I saw the link you share with us.. There are 4 sliders at the top and there are some play - pause buttons that already working correctly at the left bottom of the sliders.. Did you solve your problem, or I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Layer Actions to Play, Pause, Mute and Unmute a Video Layer following the instructions here https://www.sliderrevolution.com/documentation/media-actions/